View plots and outputs under code chunks in rmd files (VS Code)
i was trying to set up VS Code in a way to see my code output and plots under code chunks i run (similar to jupyter notebook). I know RStudio can do that for rmd files but i wanted to set up vs code in a way i could do all my coding in vs code. I would be greatfull for your help.
I was looking in R extenstion setting for "Preview after kernel execution" or anything similar but i couldn't find anything
